# Package Spring Boot application inside a React app with maven

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, maven, spring-boot

I have a working React app, and I would like to add a Spring Boot application to it. My final goal is to have **a single war file with the React app and the Spring Boot application** after running mvn clean package.

Now, if I run mvn clean package it will compile the React app and package it into a war file successfully. So far so good. But I have no idea how to compile and add a Spring Boot application to the package with the same command.

I found a similar solution: https://github.com/kantega/react-and-spring

*BUT this is not working for me*. I need the React app to be the main project, and I need it to be compiled by a maven command.

I use the *exec-maven-plugin* to tell the compiler to use yarn when I call mvn clean package. I tried to add an other goal to this plugin which complies the backend part but the result was an infinite loop.

The process should be something like this:

1. compile backend
2. compile frontend
3. package it together in a single war file

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: JHipster, take a look at it: https://www.jhipster.tech/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Lorelorelore's comment, I was able to create a solution.

With *JHipster* you can create an application like I described in the question, BUT with full of unnecessarily generated code. I removed all the irrelevant code, and added some important part, and the result was a cleaner, smaller application.

*So I created a much simpler boilerplate code.*

**Here is the GitHub link:** https://github.com/archangel1991/react-with-spring

I hope it will help :)